# Adobe Livecycle performance

Tags: openoffice.org, livecycle

I have installed Adobe Livecycle in order to convert MSWORD files to PDF from a web-app.
Specifically, I use the DocConverter tool. Previously I have used OpenOffice UNO SDK, but I have found some problems with particular documents.

Now, the conversion is ok, but the conversion time is huge.
These are the times to convert documents of different sizes via Openoffice and via Livecycle.
Could you suggest anything?

```
SIZE (bytes)    Openoffice (sec)    Adobe LiveCycle (sec)
24064           1                   8
50688           0                   3
100864          0                   3
253952          0                   5
509440          1                   5
1017856         5                   18
2098688         8                   10
4042240         19                  45
6281216         0                   9
8212480         32                  125
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind the length of time behind the transaction is how LiveCycle PDF Generator works. In order to maintain document fidelity, the document is programmatically opened using whatever native software the original document was created in, and then converted to PDF.

Consider increasing your application server heap size, and LiveCycle Document Max Inline Size. Here are two helpful articles:
[Heap Size Tuning](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2010/10/heap-size-sweet-spot-for-livecycle-es2.html) and [Large Document Processing](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2008/10/livecycle_processing_big_docum.html)

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that Adobe live cycle perform better and faster in windows rather than Solaris. Conversion of Document to PDF is always single threaded which ends up consuming more resources. Make sure to increase the heap size, Timeouts and it would serve better if load balancing is done with multiple servers.